# Why Filter doesn't catch GET requests from Postman?

Tags: java, spring, filter

I've made LoggerFilter class and when i make GET request in postman i dont recieve any log info in console.

HERE IS MY LOGGERFILTER CLASS:

```
`package FirstTest.demo.Controller;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class LoggerFilter implements Filter{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFilter.class);
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(request instanceof HttpServletRequest){
            var httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            logger.info("[doFilter]" + httpRequest.getMethod() + " " + httpRequest.getRequestURI());
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, servletResponse);
    }

}
`
```

In any controller class Logger is working.
Here are dependecies from pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I made a breakpoint in doFilter method and app is not even using it while making GET request in Postman.

Comment: Have you registered your filter in descriptor file? (web.xml)

Comment: I am using Servlet 4.0.1. @Component adnotation is not enough in LoggerFilter class ? I dont have web.xml file.